# How to display result from jar on client side from server side app.js in node js application

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

In server side app.js file I would run one jar file ,which gives the result and I store that in one variable.Now I had a route /index in my app where Iam calling html and .js file for client side from my app.js file.Now I want to display the result variable from my server side on to the client side html.How can I display that result on to my html in one textbox on button click.

app.js(main file)-server side

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -jar ./helloworld.jar',
function (error, stdout, stderr){
console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
var jardata=stdout;//In jardata Im having my response from jarfile
console.log(jardata,"jar out...");
if(error !== null){
  console.log("Error -> "+error);
}
});
module.exports = child;
app.get('/index',function(req,res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
});
```

index.html(clientside)

```
<body>
<div style="margin:100px;">
<div class="jumbotron"  style="padding:40px;">
  <h1>Hello!!!</h1>
  <div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="callJar();">Call</button>

  <input type="text" id="textbox">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

index.js(client side js)

```
function callJar(){
console.log("Hello");
var text="Hello";
var textbox=document.getElementById('textbox');
textbox.value=text;
```

}

Now how can i make jardata display in that text box can someone help!!